# mod_rewrite duplicate content

Tags: mod-rewrite

I like to get rid of duplicate content.
my site was reachable with and without www. So I did a modrewrite like this:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [r=301,nc]
```

my problem is that I can still reach the site with and without /index at the end. and with and without .html

I like the index to be shown in the URL. example.com www.example.com all redirect to www.example.com/index

The with and without html applies to all my subpages. Is there a way to always remove the html?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood what you're trying to do, but maybe this is it:

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index [L,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^index$ index.html [L]
```

This will force "www." to appear at the start of the domain, redirect requests for the bare domain or "/" to redirect to /index, and then silently rewrite requests for /index so that they actually fetch the content of /index.html.